# Unbounded Value OCAML

Tags: makefile, ocaml, ocamlbuild

I am trying to compile Orange as part of [OTAWA](http://www.tracesgroup.net/otawa/)
However I get the below Error in file  [wcee.ml](https://github.com/HazemAbaza91/Orange/blob/main/wcee)
`Error: Unbound value IMap.print_ordered`
The reason for the error is the below snippet.

```
  let glb = common

  (** Least upper bound. *)
  let lub = IMap.combine max

  (** Pretty printer. *)
  let print = IMap.print CostItem.print Format.pp_print_int

  (** Full printing. *)
  let print_complete = IMap.print_ordered ~first:"" ~firstbind:">> " ~last:"" ~sep:"@\n" CostItem.print CostItem.known Format.pp_print_int
end
```

What is the reason for that ?

Comment: Could you add more details in your question to be more "self-contained"? See [mre]

Comment: In particular: (1) there is an `end` token, but `module ... = struct` is missing; (2) The `IMap` module does not seem to be standard, so you should probably give its signature or definition.

Comment: @ErikMD I added extra information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL,DR:** at first sight, it might be possible that the project currently just FTBFS (fails to build from source)? Anyway, I didn't attempt to compile it myself, but you may want to get in touch with the [TRACES research team](https://www.irit.fr/en/departement/dep-architecture-systems-and-networks/traces-team/#tab-3) that maintains OTAWA to ask? (e.g., emailing Pr. CASSÉ…)

**Further details:**

- the latest version of the source code seems to be online at [this URL: wcee.ml](https://www.irit.fr/hg/TRACES/orange/trunk/file/c96892e53184/O_Range/wcee.ml),
- which depends on [tMap.ml](https://www.irit.fr/hg/TRACES/orange/trunk/file/c96892e53184/O_Range/tMap.ml),
- the function you mention is defined *via* `module IMap = TMap.Make(CostItem)`, which depends on the `Make` functor in the `tMap` compilation unit, which indeed does not seem to provide the `print_ordered` function,
- hence the `Unbound value` error (which just means "**this function is undefined!**")